# How to code a model with the adonis function in R (permanova) for a paired/matched design (epidemiology study)

Tags: r, bioinformatics, vegan

We have a database of 100 children that are grouped in 50 paired/matched groups (of 2 children) based on co-variables such as sex, c-section, and antibiotic treatments. We obtained the gut microbial communities for these 100 children and want to measure the influence of consumption of artificial sweeteners on microbial community structure with a regular permanova (`adonis` function in r). Each children in a pair is either at low or high level of artificial sweetener consumption. Is there any way to code a multivariate model such as we can acknowledge the paired/matched design such as in epidemiology?

I thought about the strata argument where `CHILD$pair` represents pairing of the 100 children in 50 pairs but I am not sure it does the right thing:

```
adonis(community ~ art.sweet, data=CHILD, permutations = 999, strata=CHILD$pair)
```

Comment: Seems that someone had the same problem as you and posted it on ResearchGate ;) https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_do_PerMANOVA_pairwise_contrasts_in_R

Comment: Sadly no it's not the same question. Her question is about pairwise comparison of treatments, mine is about paired design where you try to mitigate the influence of covariables by matching samples based on these covariables.

Comment: I'm not sure such a framework exists...yet. For a standard paired design, the statistical analysis is performed on the difference between pairs. In your study, I assume we have vectors of either OTU counts or proportions. So after defining a reasonable difference function between counts/compositions, you should be able to use those vectors in permanova. The problem with using strata is that the documentation says strata restricts permutations, which in this case would simply mean swapping each pair.

Comment: For compositional data, a good difference function might be found using Aitchison geometry: replacing subtraction with $x\ominus y=\mathcal{C}[x_1/y_1,\dots]$ where $\mathcal{C}$ is the closure operation that normalizes the vector sum to be 1. This transformation is equivalent to subtraction in the clr (centered-log ratio) and ilr (isometric log-ratio) data spaces. It also might be worthwhile to perform all analyses in one of these transformed vector spaces.

Comment: Also, after differencing, I supposed you wouldn't even need (and could not even use) a permanova, but a test that a multivariate mean is different from zero, such as Hotelling's T-test, a multivariate extension of the univariate t-test.

Comment: Of course, it might be better still to avoid permanova and/or transformation and use uniivariate negative binomial regression on counts for each feature (OTU) separately (this allows you to incorporate total read data as well).  Just another option. If you are really ambitious/have access to a powerful computing cluster, you could try a multivariate GLM.